# I do not know how to change double dots with after_stat() in may R code chunk in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change ..dx.. and ..dy.. to after_stat() function in my code below because in the newest version of ggplot2 it is deprecated.

```
ggplot(data = europe_wind_stream) +
  geom_sf(
    data = europe_sf,
    fill = NA,
    color = "grey40",
    size = .25,
    alpha = .99
  ) +
  metR::geom_streamline(
    aes(
      x = lon,
      y = lat,
      dx = u,
      dy = v,
      color = sqrt(..dx..^2 + ..dy..^2),
      alpha = sqrt(..dx..^2 + ..dy..^2),
      linewidth = sqrt(..dx..^2 + ..dy..^2),
    ),
    L = 2,
    res = 10,
    n = 60,
    arrow = NULL,
    lineend = "round",
    inherit.aes = F
  )
```

I have made these changes but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
ggplot(data = europe_wind_stream) +
  geom_sf(
    data = europe_sf,
    fill = NA,
    color = "grey40",
    size = .25,
    alpha = .99
  ) +
  metR::geom_streamline(
    aes(
      x = lon,
      y = lat,
      dx = u,
      dy = v,
      color = sqrt(after_stat(dx)^2 + after_stat(dy)^2),
      alpha = sqrt(after_stat(dx)^2 + after_stat(dy)^2),
      linewidth = sqrt(after_stat(dx)^2 + after_stat(dy)^2),
    ),
    L = 2,
    res = 10,
    n = 60,
    arrow = NULL,
    lineend = "round",
    inherit.aes = F
  )
```

Can you please help me what is the correct syntax for changing ..dx.. with after_stat() in my code chunk.

Comment: Welcome to SO. *unfortunately it doesn't work* is a rather vague description. Could you clarify what's the issue? Do you get any error message? Finally, as we can' run your code, it would be easier to help you if you could provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data, e.g. perhaps you can reproduce your issue using the default example from `?metR:: geom_streamline`?. That's what I did. And for the example your code seems to work fine.

Comment: Just wrap the entire expression in `after_stat()`, for example you change `sqrt(after_stat(dx)^2 + after_stat(dy)^2)` to `after_stat(sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2))`.

Comment: Thank you Stefan and teunbrand... "after_stat(sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2))" solve my problem...